# Mysql wrong syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, group-by

An example:

```
SELECT AVG(cost)
FROM items
WHERE seller_id=6
```

Lets say I want to find the average cost of items from seller 6 and the average cost of items from seller 10. However I need to do it in one SQL. When I do seller_id = 6 AND 7. It gives me the average cost of 6 and 7. However I want the average of 6 AND the average of 7.

This is the actual question:
Our orders have 5 priorities: "1-URGENT", "2-HIGH", "3-MEDIUM", "4-NOT SPEC", "5-LOW". Which type of orders has the highest sum of ‘total price’?

my sql:

```
SELECT SUM(o_totalprice)
FROM orders
WHERE `o_order-priority`='1-URGENT' AND '2-HIGH' AND "3-MEDIUM" AND "4-NOT SPEC" AND "5-LOW"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT seller_id,AVG(cost) FROM items 
WHERE seller_id IN (6,10)
GROUP BY seller_id
```

And if you want for all the sellers just remove the `seller_id IN (6,10)` clause

**[SQL Fiddle For 2 sellers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00659/1)**

**[SQL Fiddle for all sellers](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00659/2)**

Edit based on your question's edit

```
SELECT o_order-priority,
SUM(o_totalprice) as total
FROM orders
GROUP BY o_order-priority
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That gives you the `o_order-priority` that has the maximum sum. And if you remove the limit, that gives you total sum for all the priorities.

Comment: Now what if I only need the sql that  will get only the type of order by running it?

Comment: Just pick up the type form the result. You can discard the count

Comment: Got that, however when I use this SQL it returns o_orderpriority as the o_orderpriority...

Comment: You're using different names for fields in question and comments. Please fix those in the query and you are good to go

Comment: Im a little confused by what you mean:

Comment: `o_orderpriority` vs `o_order-priority`

Comment: This is my query: SELECT `o_order-priority`
                  FROM orders 
                  GROUP BY `o_order-priority` 
                  ORDER BY SUM(o_totalprice)
                  DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Sorry that is not the query that I suggested, so i wont comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group it using seller_id.

```
SELECT seller_id, AVG(cost) 
FROM items 
WHERE seller_id in (6,10)
GROUP BY seller_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT seller_id, AVG(cost)
FROM items
WHERE seller_id in (6,7)
GROUP BY seller_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT seller_id,AVG(cost)
FROM items
WHERE seller_id in (6,10)
group by seller_id
```

If you need seller wise AVG cost for all seller then try

```
SELECT seller_id,AVG(cost)
FROM items
group by seller_id
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit of theory before i post the code
while using aggregate functions like avg,sum etc you need to understand that average will be calculated on a particular group. say you want to find average marks of girls and boys then the grouping is based on gender. similarly in your case, you want to find average on seller 6 so basically you first need to form groups of sellers based in their seller id.

now when you have formed groups you select the group with seller id 6.
Now your query changes to

```
SELECT AVG(cost)
FROM items
WHERE seller_id=6       << Selecting the group 
GROUP BY seller_id      << Making groups.
```

If you want to learn what i did, try running this query

```
Select AVG(COST),seller_id
From ITEMS
GROUP BY seller_id
```

This would return the average cost and seller_id of all the sellers.

Hope this helps.

**NOTE**: While using a aggregate function there always should be a group by clause attached, and also the selected columns must be in group by clause. If you have more columns selected and fewer in group by clause then that would result in a error.

For your second question this query would work

```
Select MAX(SUM(o_total_price))
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY o_order-priority
```

Again same theory, group the columns, then fin the sums in each group and then select the maximum sum among the groups.

Comment: which query sir? and could you please post the exact error?

Comment: oh my bad, i totally forgot that we cannot use and aggregate function to an agregate function, this is because when max is calculated first it does not know what sum is. 
So to go about this there are two ways. One is shown by @Hanky Panky above while other is use of inline sql queries.
SELECT MAX(TOTAL)) FROM ( Select SUM(o_total_price) as TOTAL
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY o_order-priority). Here i first selected all the totals of all the priority list and then from that view/virtual table i seleted the max of totals.